# Postgresql JSON запрос по выборке двух элементов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть JSON массив.

```
cast(json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements('[{"bdate":"04.04.2016"},{"text":"test"}]'::json),'bdate') as date)
```

Существует ли функция, чтобы выдернуть не только bdate(в нашем случае), но и text? Чтобы запрос вернул строку с полями bdate и text

Comment: Поправил. Но в документации postgresql не нашел явной функции.

Comment: Так это... Просто второе выражение через запятую с другим ключом, нет?

Comment: нашел решение тут. https://github.com/plv8/plv8 писать самому функцию

Comment: Ок, напишите ответ тогда. Я так и не понял, в чём состоит вопрос, возможно, ваш ответ прояснит ситуацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   jsonb_to_record(replace(trim(both '[]' from '[{"bdate":"04.04.2016"},{"text":"test"}]'), '},{', ',')::jsonb) AS x("bdate" date, "text" text)
```

Проблема в том, что json - это массив элементов, а его функции работы с json могут преобразовать только в набор записей. Выход: или как-то "повернуть" набор строк, превратив его в массив и дальше в строку, либо превратить json в набор готовых для разбора элементов (что я и сделал).